# UIActivityIndicator stopping animating before NSFetchedResultsController finishes fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a core data request being made through a NSFetchedResultsController. The expected outcome of this code is that a `UIActivityIndicator` will `startAnimating` the call will be made, complete, and then return the table, before the indicator will `stopAnimating.

What actually happens is that the function returns before the NSFetchedResultsController gets any information and/or repopulates the TableView.`stopAnimating` is called almost instantly, and then only later does the table load.

My code is as below:

```
[_loadingActivityIndicator startAnimating];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"user"];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"connection.userId matches %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentUser.userId ]];
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstname" ascending:YES]];

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:appDelegate.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

// Perform Fetch
NSError *error = nil;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to perform fetch.");
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
}

[_loadingActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the table view reloading processing doing anything asynchronous? Conceptually, you just want to make sure you call `stopAnimating` at roughly the same time you call `reloadData` on the table, and apparently they're happening at different times. Or, the other issue that can cause this sort of weird behavior is if you accidentally did some UI updates on a queue other than the main queue.

Comment: I don't know core data, but I would suspect you need to move the stopAnimating into the delegate that you set on the fetchedResultsController if the fetch operation completion/results are indicated via that delegate.

Comment: @DonaldTrumpatemyhamster yow were right, If you make that into an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a delegate which is what is called when the fetch results have finished.
You need to move the stopAnimating call to that delegate.